# Is there any way to activate Code Prediction AI in Rider?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, rider

I recently switched to JetBrains Rider from Visual Studio to do C# programming. This is because Visual Studio is heavy on my system and it's like it was designed to operate on Systems ran by Sold State Drives. So this Rider software is kind of very light as it launches faster, loads solutions faster than Visual Studio. There is just one problem, Visual Studio 2022 had Code Prediction AI, a tool that tries to guess what the next line the programmer will type by learning the programming pattern of the programmer. This proves to be a very useful tool as I just approve the suggestions with a single tab key press and it saves time and improves productivity.

Is there a way to make Rider integrate a similar tool during the coding process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to enable `Machine Learning-Assisted Completion - C#` If you are using Rider 2021.3 or 2022.1.
Do it by ticking C# in the settings below:
`Preferences | Editor | General | Code Completion - Machine Learning-Assisted Completion - C#`

[image]

If you are curious you can see more details in the Rider's [Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-76539)

Comment: Am using Rider 2022.1.1 and the cannot find the Code Completion submenu of Editor

Comment: There is one more level of nesting. `Code Completion` is submenu for `General` which is submenu for `Editor`.